# Power BI report connect to a DB Dynamically

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a Power BI report where I have multiple databases, and each database contains the same set of SQL tables. My goal is to create a Power BI report that allows me to dynamically switch between databases using URL parameters. The report is published on Power BI Report Server.

Here are the details of my setup:

I have databases: DB1, DB2, DB3...
Each database has the same set of tables: Table1, Table2, Table3...
I want to be able to change the database dynamically by passing a parameter through the URL when accessing the report on Power BI Report Server. For example, I'd like to have URLs like:

http://yourserver/Reports/powerbi/YourReport?rs:Command=Render&Database=DB1
http://yourserver/Reports/powerbi/YourReport?rs:Command=Render&Database=DB2

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this dynamic database switching in Power BI reports published on Power BI Report Server? Specifically, how can I use URL parameters to achieve this, and are there any best practices or considerations I should be aware of?

I have tried implementing dynamic database switching in Power BI Desktop using parameters, and it works. However, when I publish the report to Power BI Report Server, the dynamic switching functionality doesn't work when passing the value with parameter through the URL.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if is it possible to implement it in Power Report Server, but as for Power BI Service as a first step you need to enable that in Options and Settings -> Settings -> Power Query Editor -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtw2t.png)

As a next step, you probably need to implement the same on the server side.

Next, you need to connect to one of your DBs.
Then, please create a parameter to be able to dynamically pick DBs. Set one of the DB paths.
As a next step, you have to open Advanced Editor and replace your DB path with a Parameter you've created.

Then save, try to change a parameter, refresh and dataset, publish and test on the server side with another path again.